# What is the best way of converting a large folder of bmp files to jpeg?

Tags: python, jpeg, bmp

I have a large folder of BMP files and I want to write a script that will loop through all the files in the folder and convert all BMP files into jpeg. I want it to continuously run as it will be used on a production line where new BMP images will be uploaded regularly.

Comment: @martineau I have been working hard at this for the last few days and I cant get pas the point of only converting one image in the file and I am struggling to get further so have come here as a last resort. I understand perfectly what this platform is used for , thank you.

Comment: If you didn't find anything then you didn't do enough research. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Pillow library. Use os.listdir to get a list of all the images to convert, then open each image with Pillow and save it as .png.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = "/image_folder/"
images= os.listdir(path)
for img in images:
    Image.open(img).save(os.path.join(path+ str(img).replace(".bmp",".png") + '.png'))
    os.remove(os.path.join(path + img))
```

Comment: that works great but I want to be able to replace the existing images also. Instead of creating a new PNG can I just replace the BMP? Im trying to save space with this conversion and leaving the BMP there doesnt solve my problem

Comment: in this case you can save the new image in the input folder and delete the old image

Comment: sorry Im kind of new to this but when I do that it just saves them both in the same folder. Do I have to add code to delete the BMP files?

Comment: Yes i have just added the code to remove the .bmp image

Answer (score 2):

***A single run of this code will give you the expected output.***

```
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir,path

file_path = '.'
file_format = '.jpeg'
for file in listdir(file_path):
    file_name, file_type = path.splitext(file)
    try:
        if file_type not in [file_format, '.py','.png']:
            im = Image.open(file_name + file_type)
            im.save(file_name + file_format)
    except (IOError, OSError):
        print('Error: {} Conversion'.format(file))
```